# How to cast tuples in a "for in" enumeration in swift?

Tags: casting, swift, enumeration

My enumeration is as follows:

```
for (i, poi) in enumerate(self.pois) {
//
}
```

I'd like to cast i and poi as (int, NSDictionary)

I tried many things, including:

```
for (i, poi) in enumerate(self.pois) as [(int, NSDictionary)]
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

this little package may be helpful for you:

```
let justAnArray: Array<(i: Int, poi: NSDictionary)> = Array()

// fill the array...

for temporaryTuple: (i: Int, poi: NSDictionary) in justAnArray {

    // enumerate through elements...

    println(temporaryTuple.i)
    println(temporaryTuple.poi)
}
```

---

## or

with `typealias`:

```
typealias CustomTuple = (i: Int, poi: NSDictionary)

var justAnArray: Array<CustomTuple> = Array()

// fill the array ...

for temporaryTuple: CustomTuple in justAnArray {

    // enumerate through elements...

    println(temporaryTuple.i)
    println(temporaryTuple.poi)
}
```

Comment: casting the `self.pois` array and letting the type of the tuple be inferred seems like the most sensible option to me.

Answer (score 0):

What is the current type of `poi`? If `poi` is a `Dictionary` then the cast is simple.

```
for (i, poi) in enumerate(self.pois.map { $0 as NSDictionary }) {
    println("\(i) : \(poi)")
}
```

Or you can do make the cast as the first line of the for loop.

```
for (i, poiDictionary) in enumerate(self.pois) {
    let poi = poiDictionary as NSDictionary
    println("\(i) : \(poi)")
}
```

If `poi` is an object, then you will need to call a method on `poi` to get the `NSDictionary`.

```
for (i, poi) in enumerate(self.pois.map { $0.toNSDictionary() }) {
    println("\(i) : \(poi)")
}
```

Comment: 2nd is what I did before asking the question. But's not great.